# DynamoDB table within table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any way to create a table inside a table with DynamoDB? I have a table that I expect to hold a lot of other information, and another table inside could be useful.

Comment: What do you envisage a "table within a table" to look like? You could store a JSON blob inside one of the fields, but it wouldn't have any hash/range capabilities so it would be inefficient to access. What goal are you trying to accomplish by doing this? There might be a better way to achieve such a goal.

Comment: Well I have a table, and I want to have an attribute with "times" that maps to an array of JSON objects that have a key of a date, and a value of {"start time": xxxx,   "end time": yyyy}. Because the amount of values in this array is dynamic (I'm appending to this array at certain times), I was hoping that this extra array could just be a table within. I also realize that you can't have attribute types of "Map," because the only attribute types that are allowed are "S, N, and B."Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If this JSON is too big, maybe you should store outside Dynamo. S3 would be a good option (store the S3 object ID in Dynamo so that you can find it easily). Dynamo charges you for each Kb read/write, so the larger your items are, the more you pay to read/write them.

Answer (score 1):

A DynamoDB table [can have a list of maps as an attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html), so you could store your JSON objects as native lists/maps within the table. However, if you're appending frequently, keep in mind that the [maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400 KB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-items), so you may be better off having a separate table and "joining" on it.